# Typing a function with arbitrary number of distinct arguments

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function called `pipeline()` It's currently typed as so

```js
function pipeline(firstFn: Function, ...fns: Function[]) {
  let previousFn = firstFn()
  for (const func of fns) {
    previousFn = func(previousFn)
  }
  return previousFn
}
```

If I use it to pipeline some functions

```js
const add = (x: number) => (y: number) => x+y
const result = pipeline(
   () => 4,
   add(2),
   add(4)
)
// 10
```

However, with this solution there is not type-checking that the argument types of the functions match the return types of the previous functions, and the return type is simple `any`.

I realize this can't be completely typed (eg, `Promise.all([])` has a max of 10 promises it can deal with before it gives up) but I'd like to have type-checking on invocations of at least a few arguments.

Comment: Exactly what sort of type checking are you trying to achieve here? Do you want the return of the `pipeline` to be typed or are you looking to have the arguments type-checked so that you get a type error when the parameter type of one argument does not match the return type of the preceding argument?

Comment: Yes I would like both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A Simple Solution

In the case where the return type of each function in the pipeline is the same, this can be achieved with generics fairly easily:

```
function pipeline<T>(firstFn: () => T, ...fns: ((arg: T) => T)[]): T {
    let previousFn = firstFn()
    for (const func of fns) {
      previousFn = func(previousFn)
    }

    return previousFn
}
```

### A more complete solution

The first thing we need to understand is *how does Promise.all to it?*

From the typescript source [lib.es2015.promise.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts):

```
all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10>(values: [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>, T3 | PromiseLike<T3>, T4 | PromiseLike <T4>, T5 | PromiseLike<T5>, T6 | PromiseLike<T6>, T7 | PromiseLike<T7>, T8 | PromiseLike<T8>, T9 | PromiseLike<T9>, T10 | PromiseLike<T10>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10]>;

all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9>(values: [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>, T3 | PromiseLike<T3>, T4 | PromiseLike <T4>, T5 | PromiseLike<T5>, T6 | PromiseLike<T6>, T7 | PromiseLike<T7>, T8 | PromiseLike<T8>, T9 | PromiseLike<T9>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9]>;

all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8>(values: [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>, T3 | PromiseLike<T3>, T4 | PromiseLike <T4>, T5 | PromiseLike<T5>, T6 | PromiseLike<T6>, T7 | PromiseLike<T7>, T8 | PromiseLike<T8>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8]>;

...

all<T>(values: (T | PromiseLike<T>)[]): Promise<T[]>;
```

They've written an overload for the function for every number of elements starting with 10 and going all the way down to the generic catch-all.

This is why Promise.all strict typing on the returned array bails out at more than 10 differently typed elements.

If you want to replicate this behaviour, you'll need to go to the same effort. Here's what this would look like for up to three parameters:

```
interface PipelineInterface {
    <T0, T1, T2>(a0: () => T0, a1: (a: T0) => T1, a2: (a: T1) => T2): T2;
    <T0, T1>(a0: () => T0, a1: (a: T0) => T1): T1;
    <T>(firstFn: () => T, ...fns: ((arg: T) => T)[]): T;
}

const pipeline: PipelineInterface = function (firstFn, ...fns) {
    let previousFn = firstFn()
    for (const func of fns) {
      previousFn = func(previousFn)
    }

    return previousFn
}

const result = pipeline(
    () => 4,
    (a) => a + 'Hello'
)
// result has type string

const result2 = pipeline(
    () => 4,
    (a: string) => a + 'Hello'
)
// Argument of type '(a: string) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: number) => string'.
```

Comment: I used the multiple declaration of the function technique to define them but this works perfectly!